# Latest Angular basic sample Error

Tags: sitecore-client, jss

I'm trying to go through all the Angular tutorial from the JSS.Sitecore side but I came across multiple issue.

1. The examples don't match the code that is getting generated
2. Getting missing modules that are not longer available online
3. It is displaying the same component 3 times

These are my errors:

`building modules 3/3 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: [ '/data',
  '/sitecore/api/layout/render',
  '/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary',
  '/sitecore/api/jss/contentsvc' ]  ->  http://localhost:3042
Unable to load manifest compiler babel-core/register (normally not a problem): Cannot find module 'babel-core/register'
path or pattern './sitecore/pipelines/**/*.patch.js' did not match any files.
copied media from: ./sitecore/assets/sc_logo.png to: sitecore\manifest\sitecore\assets\sc_logo.png
copied media from: ./sitecore/assets/sc_logo.png to: sitecore\manifest\sitecore\assets\sc_logo.png`

Do I need to clone an specific branch to get the angular basic sample app working?

Comment: what version of JSS are you using - Tech Preview 2 or Tech Preview 3?

Comment: The `babel-core` message is just a warning and should be harmless. The displaying of the same component three times is intentional, though confusing. There appears to be a bug with a broken image in the basic angular sample as well. Can you elaborate more on issues #1 and #2?

Comment: @AdamSeabridge I installed Sitecore 9 last week using the Tech Preview 9.0.1 rev 180412. Not sure if that is 2 or 3. Also I'm running the JSS cli version 8.0.3.

Now to elaborate more on issue #1. The example displayed on the sample app walkthrough, don't match the code the is getting generated by the CLI. A perfect example of the location of the <sc-placeholder> tag; the website location is showing as ```src/app.component.html``` but in the actual code is ```src/app/components/jss-route/jss-route.component.html```

Answer (score 1):

So I've just been testing this locally and here is what I did:

1) Run the jss create command like so in a new empty folder I created.

[image]

2) Everything seems to install ok
[image]
[image]

3) Cd to the new folder and run jss start, this seems to work ok:

[image]

[image]

4) Open localhost:3001 in my browser. It works but it's missing the sitecore logo for some reason (I see a 404 in the console) and the component appears to be repeated 3 times.

Is this what you mean?

[image]

> Update

if you run this on the root folder of your app:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core
```

That should get rid of the error and webpack will run without errors:

[image]

However I still see the logo error and 3 versions of the component.

Comment: If you look at the route data for the basic angular sample, the repeated component is intentional. The broken image is not though!

Comment: Thanks  techphoria414, seems a bit odd given the basic React example doesn't do this. Any reason it's intentional?

Comment: It was intended as an example of datasource and component reuse, though it is very confusing. I’ve logged internal issues for that and the broken image.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah I’d suggest you just go with a promo / news component so it’s something more re-world than the Sitecore welcome homepage component

Comment: Also what about the Babel core error. Shouldn’t that be listed in the npm config as a required module and download?

Comment: As the error states, it's actually optional (I believe just used for any manifest generation pipeline patches), but for samples, we might just add it as a devDependency to avoid confusion. Will investigate.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSeabridge, after looking at the yaml file I realized that the repeated component was intensional. But can anyone provide some example on how to fix the broken image?

Comment: I’m at Sugcon right now so I’m not 100% sure as can’t look at the code. My guess would be go to where app is installed and go to the /Sitecore/assets folder and upload an image called sc_logo.png

Comment: FWIW we've fixed the broken image, and disabled the duplicated content by default to avoid confusion. The babel-core thing is completely expected and does not require any resolution - the manifesting tool is smart enough to understand TypeScript or ES6/babel. The message just means that you've only got TypeScript installed, which is normal for an Angular project. A React/ES6 project would similarly have such a message about TypeScript not being found.

Comment: Great, thanks @KamFigy. This all makes sense. I'll have another go with the example when I get a minute.